# What is the best Way to Export CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I'm new in CouchDb, And sometimes I need to export my Database. 
Until Now I used this command

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/nomeDB/_all_docs\?include_docs\=true > /Users/bob/Desktop/db.json
```

But in this way, before import my Dump with this command

```
curl -d @db.json -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/dbName/_bulk_docs
```

I have to correct the Json with

```
"rows": [   =====>   "docs": [
```

And in this way My documents have one more key, the doc key.

What is the best way to do a Dump to pass, for example, to another developer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest export/import and backup/restore strategy is to simply copy the raw database file. Usually, this file is located at `/var/lib/couchdb/my-database.couch`. You can safely copy this file, even while the database is running. ([Source](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_make_filesystem_backups))

Another option is to use [replication](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/replication/index.html) to copy entire databases between servers. This option can be done incrementally, unlike the first.

Comment: thanks a lot. in this way `/var/lib/couchdb/my-database.couch` Do I Have even the attachments ?

Comment: Yes, you get the attachments too. :)